# Why would a <script> tag contains HTML comments in it?

Tags: javascript, html

In this app I'm working on I see this pattern a lot:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    doStuff();
//-->
</script>
```

What purpose might those comment tags serve? Can I safely remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ancient times some browsers didn’t understand the `<script>` tag so it was made in a way that you can add comments to the beginning without issues. This causes anything inside to not be shown on the page if the browser doesn’t know what to do with the tag.

This hasn’t been needed in a very long time so it’s safe to remove them.